# Adding Image to random fact generator (Android)

Tags: java, android

working on an android app at the minute that implements a random trivia generator. I have the facts generating at random using a button to load another string held in an array.

However, I want a specific image to appear with each quote using ImageView but not too sure how to code it. Do I need to create an array of objects and subsequently call each object using the generator or add the images (R.drawable...) to the array using another dimension?

```
public class Trivia extends Activity
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.trivia);

  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

  Random generator = new Random();
  int i;

  String[] facts;
  facts = new String [10];

  facts[0]= "At 5'3 Muggsy Bogues is the smallest player to ever play in the NBA.";
  facts[1]= "Tim Duncan was training to become a member of the 1992 U.S. Men’s Olympic Swim Team until Hurricane Hugo destroyed the only pool he could train in. His mortal fear of sharks kept him from using the ocean temporarily. So to keep in shape, he began playing basketball.";
  facts[2]= "When Wilt Chamberlain became the first NBA player to earn $100,000 in salary in 1965, his longtime rival Bill Russell demanded that his own salary be raised to $100,001. His salary was immediately raised.";
  facts[3]= "Kobe Bryant’s parents had to cosign his first NBA contract because he was only 17 when he was drafted.";
  facts[4]= "Latrell Sprewell (famous for choking his coach) turned down a $21 million contract offer claiming it wasn’t enough to feed his family. He never played again and went bankrupt.";
  facts[5]= "Shaquille O’Neal challenged Hakeem Olajuwon to one on one after losing the 1995 NBA Finals with a typewritten, signed and hand-delivered note.";
  facts[6]= "The guy featured in the NBA logo is former Laker Jerry West.";
  facts[7]= "Paul Pierce was stabbed 11 times in the face, back, and neck and still played all 82 games of the 2000-2001 NBA Season.";
  facts[8]= "Within five years of retirement, an estimated 60% of former NBA players are financially broke.";
  facts[9]= "Air Jordan’s were banned upon introduction by the NBA. However, Jordan continued to wear them anyways, as Nike was willing to pay the fine each game.";

  i = generator.nextInt(10);
  textView.setText(facts[i]);

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Trivia.this, Trivia.class);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Simple:

```
    public class Trivia extends Activity {

            @Override
            public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
                setContentView (R.layout.sample);

                Button button = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button);
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView);

                Random generator = new Random ();
                int i;

                ArrayList<SampleModel> list = new ArrayList<MainActivity.Trivia.SampleModel>();
                list.add (new SampleModel ("At 5'3 Muggsy Bogues is the smallest player to ever play in the NBA.", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
list.add (new SampleModel ("At 5'3 Muggsy Bogues is the smallest player to ever play in the NBA.", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
list.add (new SampleModel ("At 5'3 Muggsy Bogues is the smallest player to ever play in the NBA.", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
list.add (new SampleModel ("At 5'3 Muggsy Bogues is the smallest player to ever play in the NBA.", R.drawable.ic_launcher));

                i = generator.nextInt (10);
                textView.setText (list.get (i).getQuote());

                button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick (View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent (Trivia.this, Trivia.class);
                        startActivity (intent);
                    }
                });
            }

            public class SampleModel {

                String quote;
                int    drawable;



                public SampleModel (String quote, int drawable) {

                    super ();
                    this.quote = quote;
                    this.drawable = drawable;
                }

                public String getQuote () {

                    return quote;
                }

                public void setQuote (String quote) {

                    this.quote = quote;
                }

                public int getDrawable () {

                    return drawable;
                }

                public void setDrawable (int drawable) {

                    this.drawable = drawable;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: this looks good, however there is an error relating to the line: textView.setText (list.get(i));

Comment: the facts are only appearing when this amendment is made. is there a way to call the object to get the R.drawable and quote to show?

Comment: There is a method in samplemodel called getDrawable()

Comment: yeah so i added a line similar to;
textView.setText (list.get (i).getQuote());

...to call the drawable;
image.setImageAlpha(list.get(i).getDrawable());

...and the image still is not appearing. Any suggestions?

Comment: myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(item.get(i).getDrawable() );

Comment: that's working now. thank you for the patience and help my friend :)

....still learning

Comment: unfortunately it requires 15 reputation, this is my first time using stack overflow. sorry buddy :/

Answer (score 0):

Use table of drawables resource ids and randomly choose one of those ids. Then load appropriate drawable to ImageView using setImageResource method. If every message is strictly connected with particular drawable use a Map.